# Sorting files based on their extension and moving them to their directories

Tags: ubuntu, sort

I have a script that takes in all the different types of extensions in a file and creates a directory from them.

However, I need to create a directory for only 3 types of extensions. JPG/JPEG, DOC/DOCX, and 1 directory with other types of extensions "miscellaneous".

This is my script so far.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
exts=$(ls | sed 's/^.*\.//' | sort -u)
for ext in $exts; do
  mkdir $ext
  mv -v *.$ext $ext/
done
```

Comment: It is not clear from your post what the question is / where you are facing problems. Please edit your question to clarify. Also, what shell are you using (`bash`, `dash`, `zsh` ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, in `bash`, with the [regex binary opertaor `=~`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html):

```bsh
# create an array of "known" extensions
known_ext=(jpg jpeg doc docx)

# loop over the files
for f in *; do
  # if not a file keep looping
  [ ! -f "$f" ] && continue
  # if file has a known extension
  if [[ " ${known_ext[@]} " =~ " ${f##*.} " ]]; then
    # create the dir if not exists
    mkdir -p "${f##*.}" &&
    # and move the file to that dir
    mv -- "$f" "${f##*.}"
  else
    # else create dir miscellaneous if not exists
    mkdir -p miscellaneous &&
    # move the file
    mv -- "$f" miscellaneous
  fi
done
```

Comment: I have some files that doesn't have an extension at the end of the file name. For example, the majority of the files are text/plain documents. How do I insert them into the misc directory?

Comment: Their files are supposed to go to miscellaneous. Here's a screenshot to help visualize it: https://prnt.sc/zuz6xm.

Comment: @GlassDow Updated the command to account for files with no extensions and check that they are regular files and not directories.

Comment: Note that it would move a `foo.jpeg doc` file into a `jpeg doc` directory. You might as well use `known_ext=jpg.jpeg.doc.docx` and do `case ".$known_ext." in (*."${f##*.}".*) ...` (and make it standard `sh` syntax).

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
# speed things up by making mv builtin
zmodload zsh/files

# associative array giving the destination directory for each
# type of file
typeset -A dst=(
  doc  doc
  docx doc
  jpg  jpeg 
  jpeg jpeg
)

# default for files with extensions not covered by $dst above or
# files without extension
default=miscellaneous

mkdir -p $dst $default || exit

for f (*(N.)) mv -i -- $f ${dst[$f:e:l]-$default}/
```

- `*(N.)` expands to all the non-hidden *regular* files (`.`) in the current directory (with `N`ullglob so it expands to an empty list if there's no such files).
- `$f:e:l` is the `f`ile's `e`xtension, converted to `l`ower case (so both `FILE.DOCX` and `file.docx` are moved to `doc`.
- `${var-default}` is the standard/Bourne operator which expands to `default` if `$var` is no set (here applied to associative array elements).

`zsh`'s builtin `mv` doesn't support the `-v` option (a GNU extension), but you could instead use `zmv`. Instead of the loop:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -v '*(#qN.)' '${dst[$f:e:l]-$default}/$f'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would run the following commands

```
mkdir miscellaneous doc jpg
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.doc" -o -name "*.docx" \) -exec mv -v {} doc/ \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" \) -exec mv -v {} jpg/ \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -v {} miscellaneous/ \;
```

You can check if it works as you want with the following test:

```
touch foo.mp3 foo.mp4 foo.doc foo.docx foo.jpg foo.jpeg foo.png foo
```

run the commands above and check with `tree` how the files were moved:

```
tree
.
├── doc
│   ├── foo.doc
│   └── foo.docx
├── jpg
│   ├── foo.jpeg
│   └── foo.jpg
└── miscellaneous
    ├── foo
    ├── foo.mp3
    ├── foo.mp4
    └── foo.png

3 directories, 8 files
```